# Logback does not resolve file name date pattern on creating log files

Tags: java, logback

I have a simple appender like this:

```
<appender name="errorAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <append>true</append>
    <file>logs/error-%d</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>logs/archive/error-%d.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <MaxHistory>30</MaxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>[%date{ISO8601}] [%X{requestId}] [%logger{0}] %msg%ex%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
        <evaluator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.OnMarkerEvaluator">
            <marker>MY_MARKER</marker>
        </evaluator>
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>
</appender>
```

It creates log files properly, but they are named as `logs/error-%d` instead of `logs/error-2019-04-19`. I also tried to use pattern  `logs/error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}`, but it produces the same file name and does not replace the date pattern with current date.

How can I force Logback to create files with current date instead of placeholders?

Logback's debug info: [image]

Answer (score 3):

Try removing `<file>logs/error-%d</file>` . You can use this format: `%d{yyyy-MM-dd}`

Comment: I can't remove `<file>logs/error-%d</file>`, as i need to roll files to another directoty on their compression. And i also tried `%d{yyyy-MM-dd}`, it produces files with `error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}` name